# Наложение стилей на progress bar

Tags: html, css

Решил оформить Progress bar. Что прописать в CSS, чтобы зелёная часть (та, которая отвечает за процент загрузки) была красного цвета?

Comment: какая зеленая часть, какой прогресс... какой браузер...

Comment: Ну chrome, а opera, firefox и safari не обязательно. Прогресс тот который html5 <progress> Та зелёная  которая отвечает за то сколько  % загрузилось

Comment: По этому вопросу, можете [почитать эту статью](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-progress-bar/), только идеального решения на сегодняшний день - нет.