# Свои стили и анимирование Progress bar-а

Tags: html, css, css-animation

У меня есть макет в PSD в котором я нашел элемент progress.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я делаю первые шаги в вёрстке, потому не знаю как сбросить стандартные стили и проанимировать этот элемент не используя javaScript

Comment: Прочитайте про `animation-name`(и т.д. `animation-*`) и `@keyframes`, ну и желательно про `transform` тоже почитать и вопросы должны отпасть сами.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Наложение стилей на progress bar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/217233/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-progress-bar)